# Modifying items in initComponent()

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I create some items in `initComponent()`
Problem is, `this.items` somehow referes to the class variable, not to the instance variable.

So when I make two instances, I end up with two buttons.

```
items: [],
initComponent: function() {
  this.items.push( { xtype: 'button', ... }) ;
  this.callParent( arguments );
}
```

Since I have to use push, every time new elements get pushed in.

Is there some instance equivalent to `this.items` where I can modify the definition before the button gets created or do I have to check for duplicates manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't `return this.callParent( arguments );`

Just this is enough:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.items = { xtype: 'button', ... }; //Are you sure items is filled up here?
    me.callParent();
}
```

Also if you're writing your own 'component' and you want to pass parameters in the `Ext.create` I always do the following:

```
constructor: function (config) {
    var me = this;
    Ext.apply(me, config); 
    me.callParent();
}
```

This will overwrite your items declaration in your class with the one you hand in the `Ext.create()`

Comment: arrr. probably the `Ext.menu.Menu` wants the items to be an array. If I use an object, the items don't get created. If I use an array and push the items in, they get created, but every time the initComponent gets called, there get more pushed in, this is why I ended up with this problem in the first place :( edited code in my question

Comment: initComponent just gets called once though, items can be array or 1 object (which gets converted to an array after).

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for this for way too long.

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the constructor and tweak the config in there:

```
constructor: function(config)
{
  config.items.someButton = { xtype: 'button', ... };
  this.callParent([config]);
}
```